# Different brightness merging multiple BMP files into MP4 using ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg, video, video-conversion

I want to edit a small video frame/image by image without losing quality (or without losing much of it). I have used ffmpeg to split into images using the following line:

`ffmpeg -i test.mp4 $filename%%03d.bmp`

This worked fine. I tried merging the images back using several lines including:

`ffmpeg -re -f image2 -framerate 30 -i $filename%%03d.bmp -c:v prores_aw -pix_fmt yuv422p10le test.mkv`

Though, this results in a difference between brightness/contast between original and merged videos. The merged file would be a bit darker (you have to look close) than original file. What can I do to fix this?

Thanks for your time.

Comment: Hi, I am facing the same issue. I am using h264 codec and mp4 as container format. Steps:
1. split video to 3 components: <1> - <2> -<3> using ffmpeg cut (-ss, -t)
2. write the frames from component 2 to disk using "ffmpeg -i {video_file}.mp4 -vf 'fps={video_fps},format=yuv420p' {out_folder}/{prefix}%d.png"
3. convert these frames to video using: "ffmpeg -f concat -safe 0 -i '{frames_txt_file}' -c:v libx264 -vf 'fps={frame_rate},format=yuv420p' '{output_video_path}'.mp4"
4. concat: <1> - <new 2> - <3>: will result in the middle component to be a little darker. shift is clearly visible?

Answer (score 0):

For getting correct colors (and brightness/contrast), we may manually select [BT.709](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rec._709) color standard, and mark the stream metadata as BT.709 using [bitstream filter](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-bitstream-filters.html#prores_005fmetadata):

`ffmpeg -f image2 -framerate 30 -i $filename%%03d.bmp -vf scale=out_color_matrix=bt709:out_range=tv -c:v prores_aw -pix_fmt yuv422p10le -bsf:v prores_metadata=color_primaries=bt709:color_trc=bt709:colorspace=bt709 test.mkv`

---

Testing using synthetic images:

- Generating 10 synthetic BMP images using FFmpeg:
  `ffmpeg -f lavfi -i testsrc=size=1280x720:rate=1:duration=10 test%03d.bmp`
- Encoding with the original command:
  `ffmpeg -y -f image2 -framerate 30 -i test%03d.bmp -c:v prores_aw -pix_fmt yuv422p10le test1.mkv`
- Encoding with `scale` filter and bitstream filter:
  `ffmpeg -y -f image2 -framerate 30 -i test%03d.bmp -vf scale=out_color_matrix=bt709:out_range=tv -c:v prores_aw -pix_fmt yuv422p10le -bsf:v prores_metadata=color_primaries=bt709:color_trc=bt709:colorspace=bt709 test2.mkv`

---

`test001.bmp` (converted to PNG):
[image]

Playing `test1.mkv` using MPC-HC media player:
[image]
Video is darker, and colors are shifted...

Playing `test2.mkv` using MPC-HC media player:
[image]
Colors are the same as the original BMP file.

Comment: Thanks for the effort but that does not help with the issue. Appreciated though. The output from this is also darkened. I am using Windows 7 if that matters.

Comment: I didn't recognize the powershell syntax... Since you are using Windows 7 it is probably related to the video player. Windows 7 doesn't support HDR video (yuv422p10le), and the Player converts the video to sRGB. Try `ffplay test.mkv`. Try playing using VLC. Try installing latest [K-Lite Codec Pack](https://codecguide.com/download_kl.htm), and play the video using MPC-HC. In case it's not working, please share a BMP image file that reproduces the issue.

Comment: VLC doesn't use windows codecs nor does SMPlayer.  I would suggest verifying using one of these and not anything that uses a windows codec (which is a wildcard).  A BMP file has specific colors per pixel and shouldn't be affected by "interpretation".  I don't know your solution but thought that I should chime in.

Comment: Thank you for the replies. Though this is not actually a player issue. I have asked on one of the discord channels and someone who has Windows 10 verified the issue was in the output video itself. Though he said that using his own command he did not have issues with my video sample. I could not personally verify this because I have Windows 7.

Comment: Are you saying you tested with VLC Player, and had the same darker output? If so, the issue is not related to Windows 7 versus Windows 10. Can you reproduce the issue using synthetic BMP images: `ffmpeg -f lavfi -i testsrc=size=1280x720:rate=1:duration=10 test%03d.bmp` ?

Comment: @Rotem From what I saw this is an issue with gamma and ffmepg. I am not sure why why this happens and on which cases but the issue is indeed with gamma. If you want me to do any tests I am okay with that. Contact me on discord @ lomano#8904 Feel free to post the result of the tests in here if you wish.

Comment: Did you check my test example using synthetic images? Did you try using VLC Player, and had the same darker output?